# Quoted value being treated as a integer

Tags: javascript, string, type-conversion

Why does this statement  1+ +"2"+3 returning 6 in javascript?

```
console.log(1+ +"2"+3) // 6.
```

Between the two plus (+) operands there is a single space. Even though we have a quoted string it's treating the string as a number, which is confusing to me.

Can someone please explain this?

Comment: Because of [implicit coercion](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/types%20%26%20grammar/ch4.md)

Comment: Read it like this: `((1 + (+"2")) + 3)`

Comment: @llama: *Very* succinct and clear, nice one.

Comment: @llama, your link helped me.. thanks

Answer (score 7):

Because the `+` in `+"2"` coerces `"2"` to `2`, thus you get `1 + 2 + 3`, thus `6`. The unary¹ `+` has higher precedence than the binary² `+` (e.g., it happens first). MDN has a reasonably good precedence chart [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence).

E.g., starting with `1 + +"2" + 3`, then:

1. The `+"2"` part is done first, resulting in `2` because that unary `+` converts the string to number (the same way `Number("2")` would). So now we have `1 + 2 + 3`.
2. `1 + 2` is done next because the binary `+` operator (whether addition or concatenation) is left-to-right associative. So that gives us `3` and we have `3 + 3` left.
3. `3 + 3` is done, giving us `6`.

E.g.:

```
1 + +"2" + 3
1 + 2 + 3
3 + 3
6
```

---

¹ A "unary" operator is an operator accepting only one operand, e.g. the `+` in `+"2"` (where `"2"` is the operand)

² A "binary" operator is an operator accepting two operands, e.g. the `+` in `1 + 2` (where `1` and `2` are the operands)

*(There are also "ternary" operators which accept three operands; JavaScript's only current ternary operator is the conditional operator: `test ? result1 : result2`)*

Comment: `+ in +"2" coerces "2" to 2` How do you mean? When I do `console.log('1 +"2"')` I get `"12"` not `3` which means that specific `+` doesn't  turn `"2"` into `2` but instead does a string concat between `"1"` and `"2"` , otherwise it would be `3`, no?

Comment: @Fran: *"When I do `console.log('1 +"2"')` I get `12` not `3`"* Well, no, if you do `console.log('1 +"2"')`, you get `1 +"2"` because of those internal quotes. If you meant `console.log(1 +"2")`, that's using just the binary `+`, whereas the OP's using both the binary and unary `+` (the OP has `1 + +"2"`, not `1 + "2"`; note that there are *two* `+`s in there). Unary `+` on a string converts the string to number the same way `Number(str)` does.

Comment: I assume it's the same when doing `1 +"2"` in the console without the `console.log()` then as that also results in `"12"` too. I think I understand.

Comment: @Fran: Compare doing `1 + "2"` with `1 + +"2"`. (And yes, the `console.log` just shows the result, it doesn't influence the operation. That would be hugely problematic.)